# How to know file path from binary python file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am noobie in python.

I have seen a file in my /usr/bin/xyz.py. Whenever I execute it, It get some work done(not related to the question.)

My question is I want to find where the code of this file (which is generating this python file. I am saying so whenever I write name of file in my terminal and press enter it start executing it. and also i tried open it with vim. The file has unreadable characters) Is it possible to find the code ?

I get this whenever I open a file with vim. I am remotely opening it.

[image]

Comment: What "this binary file" are you talking about? Python scripts are usually not in binary format.

Comment: if you mean a .pyc file, those have the same names as their corresponding .py files

Comment: /usr/bin/xyz.py <----- the python file. whenever i open this with vi. It shows unreadable character. I thot it is binary.

Comment: @sudonym No, it is .py file. Whenever I write the file in my terminal and press enter. It get started executing and do the job I want.

Comment: you answered the question yourself. you create it running code in your terminal

Comment: @sudonym Whenever I try to open the file, the content are not readable. Please see the image attached.

Comment: That's an ELF file, not a Python script.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks. But the file has a extension of .py . Does that make sense ?

Comment: The extension is lying. Deal with it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams hang on, it might be some sort of cx_freeze. See the Py_Initialize?

Comment: @Bharel: Sure, but that just makes it compiled Python bytecode embedded in an executable.

Comment: I think he has only copied the executable file (may be elf or cx_freeze). I have tried it with some other random name, It is still executing. My Bad. Anyways,Thanks a lot guys for the help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

These are Python's file types:

`.py` files are not binary files, they are pure Python code.

`.pyc` and `.pyo` are Python compiled files (which are not fully binary either). The only difference is that the latter is optimized.

`.pyw` does not say anything about being a binary or not. It just doesn't open a console window on Windows machines. (Runs using `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` by default)

Any text editor should be able to open `.py` files correctly.

---

According to your screenshot, it might be python code compiled with some sort of py2exe just in elf. Maybe cx_freeze?

Getting out the code will not be easy at all:  You can either get it straight out from memory by using a debugger like gdb or attempting to decompile it somehow. Even then you would only get the .pyc which is a barely understandable piece of code.

Comment: A note that if you want to manually generate .pyc files you can use `python -m compileall .` in the directory containing the files you wish to generate them from, and .pyw files are run without opening a console window on Windows machines as they are run by `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`

Comment: @MoxieBall Didn't elaborate on `.pyw` as he's using unix but I've added it for the sake of completeness. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Bharel I tried to open the same file. But it is not readable.

Comment: Please see the image attached.

Comment: @ManishGadhock That's odd. It might be python code compiled with some sort of py2exe just in elf. Maybe cx_freeze?

Comment: @Bharel Is there any way, I can get the py code by this. Or its just an executable file. No way for it ?

Comment: There might be a way for you to get the py code, but it won't be easy, not at all. You can either get it straight out from memory by using a debugger like gdb or attempting to decompile it somehow. Even then you would only get the `.pyc` which is a barely understandable piece of code.